# Rinsim, load leuven map by dynamicgraph and consider collisionAvoidance. end up with there is too short connection in the graph

Tags: rinsim

I am trying to do route planning with Rinsim. And I want to take collisionAvoidance into account, So I load the map by this method (because it seems collisionAvoidance is only supported in dynamicGraph):

```
private static ListenableGraph<LengthData> loadGrDynamicGraph(String name){
    try {
        Graph<LengthData>  g = DotGraphIO.getLengthGraphIO(Filters.selfCycleFilter())
                .read(DDRP.class.getResourceAsStream(name));
        return new ListenableGraph<>(g);

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    return null;
}
```

and I set the vehicle length as 1d and the distance Unit as SI.METER. And it ends up with the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid graph: the minimum connection length is 1.0, connection (3296724.2131123254,2.5725043247255992E7)->(3296782.7337179,2.5724994399343655E7) defines length data that is too short: 0.8.
>
> at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:146)
>   at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl.checkConnectionLength(CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl.java:261)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.RoadModelBuilders$CollisionGraphRMB.build(RoadModelBuilders.java:702)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.RoadModelBuilders$CollisionGraphRMB.build(RoadModelBuilders.java:606)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.DependencyResolver$Dependency.build(DependencyResolver.java:223)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.DependencyResolver$Dependency.(DependencyResolver.java:217)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.DependencyResolver.add(DependencyResolver.java:71)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.ModelManager$Builder.doAdd(ModelManager.java:231)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.ModelManager$Builder.add(ModelManager.java:212)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.Simulator$Builder.addModel(Simulator.java:324)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.examples.project.DDRP.run(DDRP.java:86)
>       at com.github.rinde.rinsim.examples.project.DDRP.main(DDRP.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

I tried to change the vehicle length, but the error still exit. Does anyone know how to overcome this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graph from OpenStreetMap (such as the map of Leuven) is not meant to be used in combination with the [CollisionGraphRoadModel](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/core/model/road/CollisionGraphRoadModel.java) that you are trying to use. The reason is that the `CollsionGrahpRoadModel` is meant for a warehouse-like environment, not a public street. This model doesn't support multiple parallel lanes which is unrealistic in a city. The [WarehouseExample](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/examples/warehouse/WarehouseExample.java) defines two example graphs that can be used in combination with the `CollsionGrahpRoadModel`.

Comment: Thank you. Currently I am using the graph created in WarehouseExample, it works fine.